# Create Database View Dependency Tree for View Recreation after CASCADE

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift, database-administration

I have a view in my database where each record has two columns: source and dependent. In the source column is the name of a table/view in the database for which it is a source of the view name found in the dependent column. Using Python, I'd like to create another table that can be utilized to recreate views when their source table has been dropped using a CASCADE.

I know I can do this in SQL using CTEs for each "level" of dependencies. However, I have to hard code for each level and I need the number of levels to be dynamic, fitting to the number of levels implemented in the database. For instance, if view 'b' is dependent on table 'a' there are two levels and I can code for those 2 levels. But if view 'c' is created, dependent on view 'b', there are now 3 levels and I would need to know of the added level and add it to my code.

Answer (score 0):

You can get what you want with just SQL using a Recursive CTE. For visualization I added an extra level to your example.

```
--- set up 
create table view_dependencies (source_view text, depends_on_view text);

insert into view_dependencies( source_view, depends_on_view)
values ('b','a'), ('c','b'), ('d','c');

select * from view_dependencies;

-- show dependencies  
with RECURSIVE view_depends as (
   select source_view, depends_on_view, 1 lev
     from view_dependencies 
    where depends_on_view = 'a'
    UNION ALL
    select v.source_view, v.depends_on_view, lev+1
     from view_dependencies v
     join view_depends d on (v.depends_on_view = d.source_view)) 
SELECT * FROM view_depends;

-- extend the dependencies 
insert into view_dependencies( source_view, depends_on_view)
values ('g','d');

-- run the show dependencies query again.
```

Well since the tool you are using doesn't permit Recursive CTE I would first see it provides the ability to pass a raw SQL statement (or update the tool perhaps). But assuming that is also not available perhaps you can wrap a function around it, as below.

```
create or replace function view_dependent_tree(base_view  text)
                   returns table (source_view text
                                 ,depends_on  text
                                 ,lev         integer
                                 ) 
 language plpgsql                                    
as $$
begin 
    for source_view 
       ,depends_on   
       ,lev    
    in  
        with RECURSIVE view_depends as (
             select d.source_view, d.depends_on_view, 1 lev
               from view_dependencies d
              where depends_on_view = base_view 
              UNION ALL
              select v.source_view, v.depends_on_view,d.lev+1
                from view_dependencies v
                join view_depends d on (v.depends_on_view = d.source_view)) 
        SELECT * FROM view_depends      
    loop
        return next;
    end loop; 
    return;
end; 
$$ ;   

select source_view, depends_on, lev from view_dependent_tree('a');
```

Should you have mentioned your inability to use Recursive CTE? Well it would have been nice but to do so would imply an a priori knowledge that would be the suggestion. I'll assume it wasn't; not to worry.

Comment: This is great! Unfortunately, I'm using a version of Redshift that does not support recursive queries. I should have specified that.